# Redirect a subdomain from http to https with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, https

I have a subdomain sub.domain.com and I want a redirect http to https from sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com, so the same subdomain. I tried the redirect with cloudfront und s3-bucked, but I only got "too many redirects"!

From a main-domain with www and without www it's not a problem, as I have into s3-bucked www.domain.com and into cloudfront without www as only domain.com.

How do I get a clean redirect with the same subdomain?

Comment: What have you placed inside the Alternative Domain Names(CNAMES) field in CloudFront? It should be sub.domain.com. Also, in the 'Viewer Protocol Policy' field, you have to choose 'Redirect HTTP to HTTPS'.

Comment: Yes! With this config generate I a "too many redirects".

The problem is, the CNAME from cloudfront and the target from s3-Bucket have the same subdomain name. This construct running good with example, CNAME from cloufrond www.mydomain.com and s3-bucket-target without www....

well, only with a subdomain that configuration does not work.